# Python Reset Iterable During Timer-Based Iteration

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, iterable

I'm getting some strange behaviour when I click the `reset` button in the program below before the path is complete.
When I do so, the turtle speeds up and moves erratically while still basically sticking to the path. The more times I press `reset` the more eratic the movement becomes.

Could someone please explain how to have the `reset` button completely reset the path and avoid the problem described above?

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk

def create_reset_button_tkinter():
    """An alternative approach to creating a button using Tkinter."""
    canvas = screen.getcanvas()
    button = tk.Button(canvas.master, text="Reset", background="green", foreground="white", bd=0,
                       activebackground="green", activeforeground="white", command=reset)
    canvas.create_window(-100, 100, window=button)

def reset():
    global path_iter
    bob.goto(0, 0)
    path = [(0, 0), (20, 0), (20, 20), (20, 30), (30, 20), (40, 20), (40, 30), (50, 30), (60, 30), (60, 40)]
    path_iter = iter(path)
    go_to_next_coord()


def go_to_next_coord():
    try:
        next_coord = next(path_iter)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    bob.goto(next_coord)
    turtle.ontimer(go_to_next_coord, 500)


screen = turtle.Screen()
create_reset_button_tkinter()
bob = turtle.Turtle("square")
bob.penup()
path = [(0, 0), (20, 0), (20, 20), (20, 30), (30, 20), (40, 20), (40, 30), (50, 30), (60, 30), (60, 40)]
path_iter = iter(path)
go_to_next_coord()

turtle.done()
```

Comment: No need to call `go_to_next_coord()` inside `reset()`.

Comment: Thanks, but now if I click reset when the path is finished nothing happens...

Comment: You can check whether the path iteration is completed, if yes, create the timer task again.

Comment: That's what I did in `go_to_next_coord()`. Are you saying I should do it in `reset()` too?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether there are items still in the current iterator in `Reset()` function, if no, call `go_to_next_coord()` to restart the turtle timer:

```
def reset():
    global path_iter
    num_of_items = len(list(path_iter)) # get the number of items in current iterator
    #bob.goto(0, 0)  # no need to call here as it will be executed in next call of go_to_next_coord()
    path = [(0, 0), (20, 0), (20, 20), (20, 30), (30, 20), (40, 20), (40, 30), (50, 30), (60, 30), (60, 40)]
    path_iter = iter(path)
    if num_of_items == 0:
        # restart turtle timer
        go_to_next_coord()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what advantage you get by using an `iter`, particularly when @acw1668's fix to your code has to convert the `iter` back to a `list`:

```
num_of_items = len(list(path_iter))
```

Why not simply use a `list` in the first place:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from tkinter import Button

PATH = [ \
    (0, 0), (20, 0), (20, 20), (20, 30), (30, 20), \
    (40, 20), (40, 30), (50, 30), (60, 30), (60, 40), \
]

semaphore = 0

def reset():
    global semaphore

    if semaphore:
        return  # reset already executing when 'Reset' pressed

    semaphore += 1
    empty = len(path_list) == 0

    path_list[:] = PATH  # reload path coordinates

    turtle.home()

    if empty:
        screen.ontimer(go_to_next_coord)  # execute shortly after this function exits

    semaphore -= 1

def go_to_next_coord():
    if not semaphore:
        try:
            turtle.goto(path_list.pop(0))
        except IndexError:
            return

    screen.ontimer(go_to_next_coord, 500)

def create_reset_button_tkinter():
    """ An alternative approach to creating a button using Tkinter. """

    canvas = screen.getcanvas()
    button = Button(canvas.master, text="Reset", command=reset)

    canvas.create_window(-100, 100, window=button)

screen = Screen()

create_reset_button_tkinter()

turtle = Turtle("square")
turtle.penup()

path_list = list(PATH)

go_to_next_coord()

screen.mainloop()
```

I found two issues that could still cause eratic behavior in either implementation: first, `go_to_next_coord()` can execute during the `reset()` method.  (E.g. when you ask the turtle to do something, that briefly turns control back over to the event handler and allows timers to fire.)  This caused rare unexpected visual glitches.

Second, if the button were triggered by a turtle `onclick()`, I would normally unset the event handler mapping inside the event handler code (until just before it returns) to prevent *stacking* of events.  However, since this is a tkinter button, that's outside of turtle's control. (Press "Reset" over and over quickly.)

To mitigate both problems, I introduced the simple `semaphore` variable.  (Though you could also disable and reenable the button event via tkinter commands.)  Not perfect, but better.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still trying to get my head around all the aspects.

Comment: I think I understood your meaning about unsetting the event handler mapping inside the event handler code. I used `button.configure(command=lambda: None)` to disable the button. However this only worked when I disabled the button inside the timer callback, not the button callback.